# Why are lithium (Z)-enolates more stereoselective than (E)-enolates in aldol reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereoselectivity, aldol-reaction

In aldol reactions, it is apparently a general rule of thumb that (*Z*)-enolates give higher stereoselectivity (for the *syn* aldol product) than (*E*)-enolates do for the *anti* product. Quoting Carey & Sundberg, *Advanced Organic Chemistry: Part B* (5th ed.), p 69:

> From these and many related examples the following generalizations can be made about kinetic stereoselection in aldol additions of lithium enolates.
>   [...]
>   (3) *Z*-Enolates are more stereoselective than *E*-enolates.

and the example given (taken from a Clayton Heathcock paper, [*J. Org. Chem.* **1980,** *45* (6), 1066–1081](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01294a030)) is

[image: Diastereoselectivity of aldol reaction]

Evans also mentions this in his paper comparing the Cornforth vs polar Felkin–Anh models ([*Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2003,** *42* (15), 1761–1765](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.200350979)):

> While *Z* and *E* lithium enolates are also formed with good configurational purity, the characteristic decline in *syn*/*anti* selectivity is observed, particularly with the *E* enolate.

Why is this the case? Or, why is $\Delta \Delta G^\ddagger$ for the (*Z*)-enolate larger (corresponding to greater selectivity) than for the (*E*)-enolate? I don't see anything that stands out when looking at the six-membered Zimmerman–Traxler transition states - within this model, the difference $\Delta \Delta G^\ddagger$ for *both* enolate geometries is simply the cost of putting a phenyl group axial instead of equatorial.

Comment: I can't get my thoughts into coherent sentences right now, but Heathcock (*J. Org. Chem* **1980**, *45*, 1066), and the nice (old) review In Comprehensive Organic Synthesis (Vol II, 190) give an okay explanation. tl;dr is that the aldol is kinetic but ΔG is so small that retro-aldol easily occurs to give  a thermodynamic component. Keep in mind that Li-O bond long so TS energies essentially the same.   Dave Evans' talks about this in his lectures and essentially says its a lie if the right enolate (boron not lithium) is chosen (its maybe more surprising that *any* Li aldol is selective).

Comment: All the boron aldols I performed on ketones during my PhD thesis were fully stereoselective. I either only got a single product (I wanted *anti*) or I got two different *anti*-diastereomers stemming from the Felkin and the anti-Felkin attack. This supports what NotEvans has written about NotNotEvans.